# Spark function for normal distrbution (norm.dist)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, normal-distribution, apache-spark-ml

I am looking for spark scala function to find normal distribution value like `norm.dist` in Excel. Cannot find in spark library.

Could you please help me with the function or alternate approach to achieve the same in spark? Please advise. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any sample input and output? meanwhile, you may want to look at StandardScaler - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#standardscaler

Answer (score 0):

After searching and compare calculation in excel.
We can use  NormalDistribution function to in commons.math3.distribution as followed.
Thanks for the comment.

[image]

Comment: You need this in spark, no? Try using `import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Matrices, Vectors}
    import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.distribution.MultivariateGaussian
    val gaussian = new MultivariateGaussian(Vectors.dense(Array(112.5322297)),
      Matrices.diag(Vectors.dense(22.56897774))
    )
    println(gaussian.pdf(Vectors.dense(Array(55.88))))` Supports [degenerate_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Degenerate_case)